# Why are reads from CouchDB so slow? (1.5MB/s or thereabouts)

Tags: performance, couchdb

I have a CouchDB (1.1.1) server running that contains a lot of documents in the 400-600KB size range.

If I time fetching a full document from the database (not from a view, just the raw document) it takes 200-400ms to complete which equates to around 1.5MB/s throughput.

If I write the same data to raw files on disk they load in 10-20ms (around 25-50 MB/s).

I'd expect CouchDB to have some overhead, but an order of magnitude (and some) seems crazy for what is essentially a read!

Can anyone shed some light onto why this might be the case?

**Update**: As requested below, a timing from curl:

```
# time curl http://localhost:5984/[dbname]/[documentname]

real    0m0.684s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.020s
```

The fetched document was 642842 bytes. I've tested it on both a standard 1TB harddisk and an EC2 instance (EBS volume) with similar results.

Comment: Edit: As requested below a timing from CURL

Comment: Hi, I also faced the same situation as you described. Can you share your benchmark for this? Did you really did what they suggested by testing on a lot of reads and take the median? This topic is pretty interesting to me :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is a few factors

1. You are fetching over HTTP which is fundamentally a higher-latency protocol. In particular, you are building up a TCP connection from scratch by using `curl`. (Web browsers and most client software keeps a pool of persistent, HTTP/1.1 keepalive connections.) But fundamentally, CouchDB chooses a "slower" protocol because it is so universal and so standard.
2. Your documents are on the larger size for CouchDB. Most documents are single or double-digit KB, not triple. CouchDB is encoding/decoding that JSON in one big gulp (i.e. it is not streaming from the disk.)
3. Not only is EC2 (even EBS) i/o less-than ideal for a database (it itself has high latency), but it can also fluctuate as your neighbors generate unknown i/o bursts which you compete with.
4. CouchDB is a filesystem on top of a filesystem. The .couch file looks much like a filesystem itself. So you are multiplying inefficiencies. The .couch file and metadata requires random i/o against the storage; **and** reading the document requires random i/o within the `.couch` file. You may see the effects of disk latency multiplied. Instead of comparing reading a *document* vs. reading a filesystem file, you might compare reading a document vs. reading an equivalent MySQL row.

Note, I am not saying that CouchDB is actually fast and your results are incorrect. Quite the opposite: CouchDB is slower than many people expect. To some degree it has room to improve and optimize; but *primarily* CouchDB has decided that those costs are worthwhile for the broader good it brings.

CouchDB fails the benchmarks, and aces the college of hard knocks. I suggest that you next benchmark a full load on CouchDB, simulating your expected demand for multiple concurrent access, and get as close as you can to your real-world demands on it. That will be a more helpful test and generally speaking CouchDB performs impressively there.

That said, CouchDB is a *domain-specific database* and so it may become clear that you are looking for a different tool as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jason, it's all stuff that has come to mind. I've also tested off EC2 with the same results (local disk, fast dev box). I think it comes down to CouchDB reading, parsing, and then serialising the entire document which just seems odd. If you "head" the raw database file you can see the documents almost as raw JSON, it seems odd they aren't simply streamed right out for a GET request.

Comment: I definitely appreciate it's an abstraction on an abstraction (etc) but I was surprised to what level it hinders read performance on a raw document. On a core i5 with 1TB disk and 12GB of ram I'm getting 3MB/s read (while pegging the CPU) - which is amazingly slow!

Comment: I also get that CouchDB is domain-specific, and the things it does well for us it does very well. It just seems odd that after all the time and effort it takes to pre-build views for good performance it would be let down by the read (which should[?!] be a simple fetch of the prepared data/original document from disk).

Comment: Yes it's true. I think the next step is definitely to test *concurrent* load. That will give you an additional perspective. By the way, is your database recently compacted?

Comment: Hi Jason - I did test concurrent load through our API using JMeter (this is what led me to discover the issue in the first place). It appears that the level of CPU usage is the limiting factor, so I don't see how concurrent requests would benefit since it's being pegged from a single request anyway?

Comment: Good point. Well you may have reached a legitimate misfeature ("bug" is probably too simplistic and wrong). There is already a discussion on the CouchDB users list about benchmarking and measuring performance, and *also* in the developers list about doing the same to identify regressions. If you brought this up there I think you would get good engagement to plan and execute performance improvements in CouchDB.

Comment: I also evaluated CouchDB for a particular requirement. In my case I found _write_ performance greatly below what should have been achievable -- it came in at 1/16th to 1/30th of PostgreSQL. While some aspects & ideas of CouchDB seem interesting, it seems questionable whether the product is fully realized. We have determined it is not a suitable solution for us.

Answer (score 1):

How are you retrieving the document? If you are using some code then please include that code and any libraries that you're using.

Or just use `curl` to retrieve the document. Ex., I just did `time curl http://localhost:5984/bwah/foo` and got the document in .017s. An important note is that I'm on a machine with SSDs.

Also, doing one read is not enough to suggest the throughput you can expect from CouchDB, or any server software for that matter. You need to do a lot of requests and then see what the average and median times are.

Comment: My actual testing read 1,000 similarly sized documents and the figures I've posted reflected the average across the whole sample.

Comment: What size EC2 instance? I can duplicate on my side. Also, virtual systems are going to see highly degraded performance because of I/O contention to the disk: CouchDB fsync's on every write before reporting success. Lastly, where are you running the test from - localhost, LAN, or WAN?

Comment: I ran the tests both on EC2 (EBS volume) and a standard local harddisk on my dev box (core i5, 12GB ram, 1TB disk). I believe the problem is related to the size of the documents (400-600kb each), the bottleneck during reads appears to be CPU according to dstat.

Comment: Yeah, those are pretty large document sizes. Do you see the same times with smaller docs? Also, do you have a validation function defined? Those tend to slow down writes.

Comment: No validation functions - we have no use for smaller docs, so that wouldn't help! I suspect we'll end up just keeping a copy of the raw documents on the file system for faster access when we need them.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting that you make your docs smaller. I was wondering if you see comparable write times with different sized documents.